# how to write validation for currency fields in InfoPath 2010

Tags: infopath

Hi I have an InfoPath form where there are some date fields and cost fields. Date fields are like Startdate and Enddate, Cost fields are like StartCost and EndCost.
 
My validation is such that whenever Endcost is greater than 0 and users click submit without entering any date then it should throw error message. 
I have taken a variable and assigned it to the error message and trying to show this message when the user clicks on Submit.But this is not working some how with the rules. Can someone help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use infopath **Validation rules**. you can assigned this rule on your date feild, this rule's condition check on the cost and date values and show an error message when the condition is true. 
[image]

Comment: Hi Saeed , that wont work in my scenario as this will show a pop up box when user hits submit which is InfoPath default validation error message. I am looking for something which should validate and give user friendly message. I was able to do this for all other fields except the scenario which I have mentioned in my question above. Thanks.